# Read Delta table from multiple folders

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I'm working on a Databricks. I'm reading my delta table like this:

```
path = "/root/data/foo/year=2021/"
df = spark.read.format("delta").load(path)
```

However within the `year=2021` folder there are sub-folders for each day `day=01`, `day=02`, `day=03`, etc...

How can I read folders of day 4,5,6 for example?

**edit#1**

I'm reading answer from different questions and it seems that the proper way to achieve this is to use a filter applied the partitioned column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems the better way to read partitioned delta tables is to apply a filter on the partitions:

```
df = spark.read.format("delta").load('/whatever/path')
df2 = df.filter("year = '2021' and month = '01' and day in ('04','05','06')")
```

Answer (score 2):

List them as comma separated values enclosed in curly brackets

```
path = "/root/data/foo/year=2021/{04,05,06}/"
```

or

```
path = "/root/data/foo/year=2021/[04,05,06]/"
path = "/root/data/foo/year=2021/0[4|5|6]/"
```

Comment: This did not work for me.
Got this error: 
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: `SparkApp101/src/main/resources/result/*` is not a Delta table.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove .format("delta"). from your Source code path
2. Use below UDF

   def fileexists(filepath, FromDay, ToDay):
   mylist = dbutils.fs.ls(filepath)
   maxcount = len(mylist) - ToDay + 1
   maxcount1 = maxcount - FromDay
   return [item[0] for item in mylist][maxcount1:maxcount]

   filepath = Parent File Path = "/root/data/foo/year=2021/"
   FromDay = Start day folder
   ToDay = End day folder

Note: Change the function as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` accepts a list as well as a str. In your particular example, tryp this:

`path = [f'/root/data/foo/year=2021/day={ea}' for ea in ['01', '02, '03]]`

*N.b.* glob pattern is acceptable, but not RegEx. I'm on Spark 3.2.1.